# jquery array checkbox repeating index value how to get rid of it

Tags: jquery

jquery array each function repeating last index value how to get rid of it. please help.

**jquery**

```
var addToCheckbox = function () {
      var newNames = new Array();
    $("input[name='skills']:checked").each(function ()
    {
        newNames.push(this.value);
        $("input[name='skills']:checked").prop('checked',false)
  nestableList.append('<li>'+newNames+'</li>');

  });
};

     $("#menu-checkbox").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addToCheckbox();
      });
```

**Html**

### Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect - DEMO

```
<form class="" id="menu-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="JavaScript" />JavaScript
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="jQuery" />jQuery
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="C#" />C#
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="VB" />VB
        <br /><br />
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="addButton">Add</button>
    </form>
```

**result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: buddy what is nestableList ?

Comment: its a variable var nestableList = $("#nestable > .dd-list");

Answer (score 2):

When you do `nestableList.append('<li>'+newNames+'</li>');` you append the *whole array* each time. I assume you meant to append just one element of it.

It's hard to see why you even need an array for this to be honest. You can just write  `nestableList.append('<li>'+this.value+'</li>');` directly. The array gets destroyed when the function ends anyway, so it doesn't appear to have any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It would apear that you are trying to :

- form an array comprising the values of checked checkboxes
- form a comma-separated string from the array
- append the comma-separated string to a `<UL>` or `<OL>` element
- uncheck all the checkboxes.

Try this :

```
$("#menu-checkbox").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // find the checkboxes
    var checkboxes = $("input[name='skills']:checked");

    // map the checkboxes to an array of their values
    var newNames = checkboxes.get().map(function(element) {
        return element.value;
    });

    // append comma separated string to `nestableList`
    nestableList.append('<li>' + newNames.join(',') + '</li>');

    // uncheck the checkboxes
    checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
});
```